# Can I set up a git repository to be available from several computers?

Tags: git, msysgit

Is there any way with Git (on windows) to work with the same repository from several computers ?

Actually, I'm working from either a desktop computer or a laptop. I'd to work with the same repository whatever computer is used.

I know I can use Git to push/pull from a central repository, but it's not transparent (as I have to push before switching computer).

Using an usb key could be a solution, but I have troubles when switching, as the drive letter are not the same from one computer to another.

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your repository into some kind of cloud storage like DropBox and use it from both computers.

Comment: It's an idea, but this won't solve the problem of the hard coded path in the git repository (though it's a separate question related to git). I'll give a try to Windows Live Mesh, as it provides more space.

Comment: I don`t exactly get what you mean by hardcoded paths, could you update your question and elaborate some more?

Comment: Imagine I have a repo at d:\myrepo (on a usb key). If I plug the key onto another computer where the key will be mounted at e:\, the git command will still try to use d:\myrepo when switching branches.

Comment: maybe i am getting this wrong but git works well with using relative paths. actually i think i never used an absolute path with git